# Cannot generate SSPI Context

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, connectivity

When I try to connect to a SQL Server from my local machine I get the following error:

> Cannot connect to Computer1\Instance1.
>   The target principal name is incorrect.
>   Cannot generate SSPI context.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)

When I tried to connect to the same instance through RDP, it throws the following error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>   Error connecting to 'Computer1\Instance1'.
>   Attempted to divide by zero. (mscorlib)

At the same time it is connecting successfully through CMD. It was working fine, until last night. but now I am unable to connect to it.

Comment: Please check My question. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93389/error-cannot-generate-sspi-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred because the TCP port was wrongly configured for the *instance*.

Initially, I checked named pipes and shared memory; everything was perfect. Then I discovered that the TCP/IP protocol port was mismatched, by checking the port configuration in the IP Address tab.

I enabled port 1433 for the server's IP address and pressed OK. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happen when it loses a trust relationship with the domain. One of my solutions is to open up a command window and type in `ipconfig /registerdns`, wait 15 minutes and try again.