# Connection to database causes SSPI context error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, spn

I have migrated a SQL server from another server box that was decommissioned. They have the same name and also same IP address. However, when I connect to the server from an application using trusted connection, I get the "SSPI context not generated" error.

What I have done:

- I have used the setspn -X to confirm there is no duplicate SPN.
- I have changed the order of protocol to follow the order:

  Shared Memory,
  Named Pipes,
  TCP/IP.
- I have verified that when I restart SQL server, the service registers and deregisters. This was found in the SQL server log.
- I have checked that on the SQL configuration the TCP/IP network protocol has the right IP and is active and enabled on both 32bit and 64bit.

I am running out of ideas and I am still getting the same error. I can't find any log that point to Kerberos.

Comment: Is the sysserver name changed .. sp_addservername ?

Comment: Was the name correct before you installed SQL or did you change it after?

Comment: Yes the server was changed after and the sysserver was changed as well.

Comment: Make certain that the clock on both the servers is correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Cannot Generate SSPI context](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93389/error-cannot-generate-sspi-context)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Microsoft Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server to automatically detect and fix such SPN Issues:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2013/05/21/new-tool-microsoft-kerberos-configuration-manager-for-sql-server-is-ready-to-resolve-your-kerberosconnectivity-issues/