# Old ODBC app throws "cannot generate sspi context" on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, odbc, windows-10, kerberos

An old Access 2003 .adp project is currently running on Windows 7 machines, while SQL Server 2008 is on the backend.
Since the app is moved to a Windows 10 machine, the app will trigger "Cannot generate SSPI context" error.

There are a lot of messages over the Internet to [explain possible reasons and solutions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93465/20822).

In our case, we may overcome the problem running Msaccess.exe from commandline, using:

```
runas /netonly /user:userdomain\useralias "C:\Program Files\<path-to-office-folder>Msaccess.exe"
```

The downside is that the user is prompted for password each time the shortcut is being used.

## EDIT:

The weird fact is that the context under which the program is running is apparently the same as the Windows 10 user has the right credentials to access domain resources (can access server side networks shares correctly), and also has credentials within SQL server configuration. As a proof, under Windows 7, the same credentials are being used without errors.

[image]

It looks like the app in Windows 10 is incorrectly passing computername\useralias credentials to SQL Server in place of userdomain\useralias.....

Is there a way to fix this so that the app (or Windows 10) are addressing the domain user name correctly, avoiding the error?

Answer (score 2):

When you launch your app using "runas" command, you use some domain user, and that user has Windows login at your SQL server. Or that domain user is part of some AD group that has Windows login at your SQL Server

When you launch app without "runas" command, the app is running, but under different security context (under different windows user), right ? 
In this case you have to create Windows login for this domain user at your SQL Server and grant it some permissions, so that different windows user can connect to SQL Server. That would resolve "Cannot generate SSPI context" error

`Edit 1:` after re-reading your question - its also possible that your windows 7 machine has login at your SQL Server (example "yourdomain/win7machine$") so it can connect, and when you move your app to windows 10 machine, that machine's computer account ("yourdomain/win10machine$") does not have login at your SQL Server... you just have to create this login

`Edit 2:` to find out what Windows login app is using to connect to SQL Server, while app on Win 7 machine is connected to SQL Server, run below command at SQL Server:

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

Look at columns `host_name` (it will be your Win 7 machine) and `login_name` (it will be the actual login that application is using to connect to SQL Server)

Then try to launch the app on Windows 10 machine. Make it throw "cannot generate SSPI context" error. Go to SQL Server machine, launch Event Viewer, go to Application logs. Is there a new Logon event from MSSQLSERVER ? if so, does it say "login failed for user...." ? if yes, it will show you what login app on Win 10 machine is using to connect to SQL Server

Comment: I have updated the OP. Could you clarify your last paragraph?

Comment: Last paragraph its about each computer having its own computer account, so for example if your computer name is `Win10computer`, then its computer account within domain would be "yourdomain\Win10computer$", and in order for it to access your SQL Server you need to create login "yourdomain\Win10computer$".  In some scenarios apps that are launched on Windows machine, are run in the security context of computer's account. Last paragraph says that there can be some possibility of that in your case.

Comment: Strange to say, only the Windows 10 computer is present in the AD. No trace of the Windows 7 machines. No trace of such accounts in the SQL server logins... :-(

Comment: Windows 7 machines are not joined to domain ? (you can look this up in Control Panel -> System). But in any case app seems to be running under a different security context on win 7 and win 10 machines, or its the same (some local service), but machine account for win 10 does not have Windows Login at SQL Server... To rule that last paragraph out, you just run at SQL Server "create login [yourdomain\Win10computer$] from Windows" and grant it some permissions, and try if app on Win 10 can connect after that

Comment: and if after that app still throws "cannot generate SSPI context", then you will have to find out what really context (Which Windows user) app is run under on Win 10, as it clearly different from Win 7's context; and grant that context's user access to SQL Server

Comment: Those machines (both Windows 7 and Windows 10) are not connected to the domain, although access to network shares (and SQL server is granted). Will try your suggestions

Comment: updated my Answer (look for Edit 2)

Comment: Fantastic help, will test and return ASAP!

Comment: The query you have provided will show the correct userdomain\username login ehn connecting from Windoes 7. When connecting from the offending client (Windows 10) , no error is visible in the Event log...

Comment: what is the user "userdomain\username" when it connecting from Windows 7 ?  you said both Win 7 and Win 10 are not connected to domain, so I guess its some local account ?

Comment: Seems to be confusing, but all the mentioned machines are configured with local accounts, however their access to the domain resources is granted because the same usernames & passwords pairs are registered both as local accounts on each PC and the domain Active Directory. In the end, query you have provided will show the domain-name\username NOT localAccount\username